Disable fyi-popup on the tab name containing the SQL statement information
After executing a SQL statement the result is being shown in tabs located underneath the SQL statements. If you move your mouse over the tab name an fyi pops up containing SQL statement.
Many times the fyi popup just does not disappear and stays there. This way it masks the results. You have to move over the tab names again in order to make the fyi popup go away.
I have searched the web for this problem but I could not find any solution. After that I have been through the setting options of HeidiSQL. Unfortunately there is no such option as disabling the info fyi on the tab name.

These balloon hints appearing on the result tabs can be disabled, in Tools > Preferences > Grid formatting > "Pop up SQL text over rexult tabs":

